# Unable to parse object being returned as either START_OBJECT or START_ARRAY in the response

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson, jaxb2, jersey-client

In one of the APIs of Expedia Affiliate Network, below part of the response is being returned as array for a few items whereas object for others,

```
"Surcharges": {
       "Surcharge": {
                "_type": "TaxAndServiceFee",
                "_amount": "11.94"
        },
        "_size": "1"
}

"Surcharges": {
       "Surcharge": [
            {
                    "_type": "TaxAndServiceFee",
                    "_amount": "11.94"
            },
            {
                    "_type": "Somethingelse",
                    "_amount": "11.94"
            }
        ],
        "_size": "1"
}
```

The corresponding JAXB model is

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "@size",
    "Surcharge"
})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Surcharges {

    @JsonProperty("@size")
    private String Size;
    @JsonProperty("Surcharge")
    private Surcharge[] Surcharge;
    //was not part of the original model, added hoping this might solve :(
    @JsonProperty("Surcharge")
    private Surcharge Surcharge1;

    .....
}
```

The parse fails with

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of in.xxx.xxxxx.port.adapter.expedia.hotels.list.response.Surcharge out of START_ARRAY token
```

and changing the Surcharge to array will result in

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of in.xxx.xxxxxx.port.adapter.expedia.hotels.list.response.Surcharge out of START_OBJECT token
```

What is the best way to handle this response

I could find the solution in the Jackson Feature configuration

ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, how to set that with the ClientConfig of Jersey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved configuring JacksonJaxbProvider with the Client

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

JacksonJaxbJsonProvider jacksonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
jacksonProvider.setMapper(mapper);
config.getSingletons().add(jacksonProvider);
```